# How To Populate Mysql Database Using CKEDITOR(WYSIWYG editor)?

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I am a beginner in php and working on admin side of a small website. I have attached CEditor to the admin page so that the admin may edit the page text. Here, I am a bit confused about one thing and that is about how can I connect the CKEditor with mySQL database so that the text,HTML tags or images of CKEditor should be populated to the database.

Comment: This is basic html / php / mysql interaction, google for a tutorial on how to insert into mysql database with php / form.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor does not influence your server-side stuff in any way, including MySQL. It's basically a JavaScript overlay of a textarea HTML field. Therefore, the way to connect CKEditor to MySQL is the same way as to connect a simple HTML form to MySQL. My suggestion is: experiment with putting data from regular HTML forms into MySQL, and only after you've mastered this, apply CKEditor to whatever form fields you need.